# fading angle does not work?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a figure of a dihedral angle.  The figure is 
[image]

Think that the line OB is a river and the line AC is a bridge over the river.
I want the colors to fade from the tops C and A toward the "river" OB.
I believe I managed to do that for the green triangle but I have not 
been able to achieve this for the red triangle.

I want the color to change in the direction A to N . No matter my
"fading angle" in the next instruction:

```
 \shade[shading=axis, left color=red,fading angle=-45,
 opacity=0.8](AA)--(O)--(BB)--cycle;
```

it creates a line from N towards the OA line. I have seen this
vertical line down from N using "draw", "shade", "shadedraw", with
many combinations of angles from -180 to 180. The vertical stripe is always
there.

It is like the colors
are changing along the BO line and not along the AN line. 
How can I achieve a smooth gradient coloring from the top A down to
the river OB?

Here is my complete code:
It compiles well with "lualatex" but it does not with "pdflatex" (I do not know why).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (2,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (0,3);
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);

  \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{5}
  \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords, scale=3.4]


                % steep but good
                %\def \x{ .526}
                %\def \y{ 0.5}
                %\def \z{0.69}
                %\def \r{0.756}
                %\coordinate (SOL) at (0.40480,0.5,0.76555);
                %\coordinate (SOL) at (.6881909602355868,0.5,.5257311121191336);
    \def \x{0.6881909602355868}
    \def \y{0.5}
    \def \z{0.5257311121191336}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\r{sqrt(\x^2 + \y^2)}

                % a bit flat but good.
                %\def \x{ .7442506296788073}
                %\def \y{ 0.574961742591969}
                %\def \z{0.34}
                %\def \r{0.94}

    \coordinate (A) at (\x,\y,\z);
    \coordinate (W) at (\x,-\y,\z);

    \def \pi{180}
    \def \beta{0.4*\pi}
    \def \alpha{37.60599135740172}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bx{\r*cos(\beta+\alpha)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\by{\r*sin(\beta+\alpha)}
    \coordinate (B) at (\bx,\by, \z);

    \def \beta{0.8*\pi}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cx{\r*cos(\beta+\alpha)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\cy{\r*sin(\beta+\alpha)}
    \coordinate (C) at (\cx,\cy, \z);

    \def \beta{1.2*\pi}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\dx{\r*cos(\beta+\alpha)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\dy{\r*sin(\beta+\alpha)}
    \coordinate (D) at (\dx,\dy, \z);

    \def \beta{1.6*\pi}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ex{\r*cos(\beta+\alpha)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ey{\r*sin(\beta+\alpha)}
    \coordinate (E) at (\ex,\ey, \z);

    \pgfmathsetmacro\mx{0.5*\bx + 0.5*\ex}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\my{0.5*\by + 0.5*\ey}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\nx{0.5*\x}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\ny{0.5*\y}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\nz{0.5*\z}
    \coordinate (N) at (\nx,\ny, \nz);


    \pgfmathsetmacro\bpx{0.4*\x}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bpy{0.4*\y}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\bpz{0.4*\z}
    \coordinate (Bp) at (\bpx,\bpy, \bpz);

    \coordinate (O) at (0,0,0);


                  % rename due to rotation 
    \coordinate (AA) at (E);
    \coordinate (BB) at (A);
    \coordinate (CC) at (B);
    \coordinate (DD) at (C);
    \coordinate (EE) at (D);


    \coordinate (M) at (\mx,\my, \z);
    \draw[] (M)--(N);
    \node[] at (M) {\; \; \tiny $M$};
    \node[yshift=1mm] at (N) {\tiny \; $N$};

    \node[] at (A) {\; \; \tiny $B$};
    \node[yshift=1mm] at (B) { \; \tiny $C$};

    %\draw[color=red, fill=none](A)--(B)--(CC);
    \fill[left color=white, right color=red, opacity=0.2](M)--(N)--(CC)--cycle;

    \shade[shading=axis, left color=red,fading angle=-45,
    opacity=0.8](AA)--(O)--(BB)--cycle;
    \shade[top color=red, left color=white, opacity=0.6](AA)--(O)--(BB)--cycle;
    %\draw[color=red](AA)--(BB);
    %\draw[color=red](BB)--(CC);
    \shade[shading=axis,bottom color=green!60,top color=black,shading angle=60,
    opacity=0.6] (O)--(BB)--(CC)--cycle;


                % this should be E
    \node[] at (E) {\; \; \tiny $A$};
    \node[anchor=north] at (O) {\tiny $O$};

    \draw[line width=0.5] (CC)--(AA);
    \draw[line width=0.5] (N)--(AA);
    \draw[line width=0.5] (CC)--(M)--(N)--cycle;


                % lower cone
    %\draw[line width=0.5, color=red] (O)--(AA);
    \draw[line width=0.5, color=red, dotted] (O)--(BB);
   % \draw[line width=0.5, color=red] (O)--(Bp);
   % \draw[line width=0.5, color=red] (O)--(CC);

    \coordinate (P1) at (0,-0.1, \z1);

    \node[yshift=4mm, xshift=-3.5mm] at (N) {\tiny $\delta$};

  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update:**

Using the library "shadings" from the package "tikz". That is adding
"shadings" to the \usetikzlibrary{... , shadings , ...} and the following line:

```
\shade[lower left=red!20,lower right=red, upper left=blue,upper right=blue!20,
    opacity=0.9] (AA)--(O)--(BB)--cycle;
```

I get the following figure:

[image: new dihedral angle]

which is better. Now, there are two issues here:

1. The gradient is not exactly as I wanted. From A to N.
2. Why the tiling? The tiling in the purple face and the porosity
   in the green face is weird.  Is this a resolution issue?  I have two tools to display PDF files: "okular" and "evince" is this a PDF issue? 
   In both of my display tools I can see the grids along the purple triangle.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any grid in the purple shading or "porosity" in the green shading. Just out of curiosity: what PDF viewer do you use and what version of those packages do you have installed?

Comment: Using that command you included in your question, I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W428r.png). Although I'm not sure how you want the purple shading.

Comment: @Alenanno  : This is interesting.  I will look at the same figure at home (I am at work now). It might be my own screen that is fooling with me. I can see in the purple triangle a square tiling from bottom to top and left to right.

Comment: @Alenanno : I see your figure. In your figure there is no tiling. It is completely smooth .  Here is my info of the PDF viewers:   02:46 PM Tue Dec 22$ okular --version
Qt: 4.6.2
KDE: 4.3.4 (KDE 4.3.4)
Okular: 0.9.5
 03:01 PM Tue Dec 22$ evince --version
GNOME Document Viewer 2.28.2

Comment: Can you try a different viewer like Adobe Reader? It's free. Also, just to be sure, add `\listfiles` to your preamble, compile, then check TikZ version in your *.log file, it has the same name as your *.tex file.

Comment: Actually I fixed the "tiling" effect.  For some reason when I use opacity less than 1.0 I get those things in my PDF files. It might be on the conversion from DVI (or whatever format LaTeX create) into PDF. How did you get your figure linked into the comment? Yes. Acroread is good.  I have it on my laptop (which I forgot to bring to the office). Thanks for your comments.

Comment: To load a picture here, use an answer to load it, then copy the link and just paste the link here. :)